# Texas Hold'em blind raises

Tags: texas-hold-em

In a 1/2 NL Texas Hold'em game with a $4 straddle on the button.

- The original under the gun player places a blind raise of $10 before the cards are dealt.
- The small blind who has only $1 in the pot raises to $14.
- The big blind folds.

My question is what action does the next player, who had a blind $10 raise, have?

Comment: Straddle on the button?   This does not make sense to me.

Comment: This is going to vary from casino to casino, and depend on whether or not the straddle is 'live'

Comment: @paparazzo A button straddle, is called Mississippi straddle

Answer (score 0):

So this is very odd and depends on the rules of the casino. Generally a game with live straddles functions in a manner where they are the last to act after the blinds. However, I have pretty much no experience with button straddles, I would imagine it functions in one of two ways, either they must act in turn if a raise is made before them or they act after the blinds.  Thus, either the straddler would act when action reached him after the UTG raise or after the SB/BB acts.

Additionally, I think your scenario is flawed because the small blind would not be able to raise to $14 as regardless of how you view the action, UTG raised the straddle amount by $6. Thus the SB would have to raise to at least $16 since you must always raise at minimum the size of the previous bet/raise (unless the SB was all in for $14). I would assume it would then be the straddler's turn to act in most cases and then UTG who could raise or fold at that point.  Regardless of how the straddle is treated the UTG player would still have the same options when the action reached them, but as I mentioned, the raise to $14 is an invalid raise.

Answer (score 0):

Im familiar with 2 straddles from the button (Mississippi/Sleeper Straddles). Since based on your description SB acts first, this is probably a Missi straddle where action preflop starts with SB and ends on Button. Here the min-raise is $8.

UTG blind raises. A blind raise is a normal raise (except that UTG has not seen his cards), but it is not UTG's turn to act. Since UTG has acted out of turn, it would only be binding if action does not change when it reaches him. When SB raises to $14, UTG would have all options left.

Depending on the house ruling, UTG may be forced to keep his $10 in the pot. He may then call the extra $4, or re-raise to at least $24, or fold and forfeit his $10.

Answer (score 0):

not 100% sure I am clear on the question. the player in question has all the regular options of call, raise, or fold. his raise must be at least $10 since that is the amount of the last raise.